# Как произвести инициализацию slick слайдера в fancybox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При открытии модального окна слайдер неправильно отображается до тех пор, пока не начнет кликать на слайды или ресайзить окно.

И неправильно отображается при повторном запуске модалки.

`beforeShow`, `beforeLoad` не помогает.

В чем может быть причина?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Prev 
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     width: 520,
     minWidth: 520,
     margin: 10,
     padding: 0,
     maxHeight: 300,
     height: 300,
     fitToView: false,
     autoWidth: false,
     autoSize: false,
     helpers : {
             title : {
                 type: 'inside',
                 position : 'top'
             },
             css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58)'
              }
     },
     tpl: {
      next : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"></a>',
   prev : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"></a>'
     },
     beforeLoad : function() {
      this.title = $(this.element).find('span').html();
     },
     beforeShow : function() {

       $('.h__slider-win').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        centerMode: false,
        asNavFor: '.h__slider-control',
        prevArrow:'<button class="slick-prev"></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="slick-next"></button>'
       });

       $('.h__slider-control').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,  
        asNavFor: '.h__slider-win',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        vertical: false
       });     

     }
    });
});


//  $('.h__slider-win').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
//    slidesToShow: 1,
//    slidesToScroll: 1,
//    arrows: true,
//    dots: false,
//    infinite: false,
//    centerMode: false,
//    asNavFor: '.h__slider-control',
//    prevArrow:'<button class="slick-prev"></button>',
//    nextArrow:'<button class="slick-next"></button>'
//  });

// $('.h__slider-control').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
//   slidesToShow: 5,
//   slidesToScroll: 1,
//   arrows: false,
//   dots: false,
//   infinite: false,  
//   asNavFor: '.h__slider-win',
//   focusOnSelect: true,
//   vertical: false
// });
```

```css
.h__modal {
  display: none;
  
}

.slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.fancybox {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.h__slider-win {
  max-height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>


<a href="#h-1" class="fancybox">modal1</a>

<a href="#h-2" class="fancybox">modal2</a>

<a href="#h-3" class="fancybox">modal3</a>


<div id="h-1" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="h-2" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="h-3" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- <div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> -->
```

[Пример codepen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/ObgrXX?editors=0010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем ничего так и не помогло, кроме задание дополнительных стилей.

Блок внутри модального окна, содержащий слайдер, обязательно должен быть `display: block`, а вот скрыть его можно например так:

```
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
```

При открытии окна, соответственно, блок со слайдером задаем видимым:

```
.fancybox-opened .h__modal {
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
    left: 0;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Prev 
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     width: 520,
     minWidth: 520,
     margin: 10,
     padding: 0,
     maxHeight: 300,
     height: 300,
     fitToView: false,
     autoWidth: false,
     autoSize: false,
     helpers : {
             title : {
                 type: 'inside',
                 position : 'top'
             },
             css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58)'
              }
     },
     tpl: {
      next : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"></a>',
   prev : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"></a>'
     },
     beforeLoad : function() {
      this.title = $(this.element).find('span').html();
     }
    });
  
  
  $('.h__slider-win').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    centerMode: false,
    asNavFor: '.h__slider-control',
    prevArrow:'<button class="slick-prev"></button>',
    nextArrow:'<button class="slick-next"></button>'
  });

  $('.h__slider-control').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,  
    asNavFor: '.h__slider-win',
    focusOnSelect: true,
    vertical: false
  }); 
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.h__modal {
  display: none;
  
}

.slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.fancybox {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.h__slider-win {
  max-height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.h__slider {
    width: 520px;
}

.h__modal {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,2,0.81);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,2,0.81);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,2,0.81);
}

.fancybox-opened .h__modal {
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
    left: 0;
}

.h__slider-win__item {
   height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>


<a href="#h-1" class="fancybox">modal1</a>

<a href="#h-2" class="fancybox">modal2</a>

<a href="#h-3" class="fancybox">modal3</a>


<div id="h-1" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="h-2" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="h-3" class="h__modal">
<div class="h__slider">
    <div class="h__slider-win">
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-win__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="h__slider-control">
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="h__slider-control__item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S**: для `.h__slider` необходимо задавать ширину (`max-width`, `width` - не срабатывают).

Answer (score 2):

Я запустил инициализацию слайдера в `afterShow`, убрал инициализацию слайдера вне фэнсибокса, убрал `.refresh()` до вызова — вроде бы работает так, как ожидается; скриншот: http://prntscr.com/ddy6dt.

---

Форк вашего кодпена: http://codepen.io/sandmanisdancing/pen/eByYLm

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
$("[data-src='#product-modal']").click(function() {
    setTimeout(() => $('.product__view__slider').slick('setPosition'), 100);
})
```